# Adding images to firebase storage with react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

Can you help me what is my mistake here? He did that in a video I watched.

The error I get is this;

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'media.cancelled')

```
const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState(false);
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);
  const [downloadUrl, setDownloadUrl] = useState();
  const [uploadTask, setUploadTask] = useState();
  const [uploadTaskSnapshot, setUploadTaskSnapshot] = useState({});


    
const onTakePhoto = () => {
        launchCamera({ mediaType: 'photo', saveToPhotos:true }, onMediaSelect())
      };

  const onSelectImagePress = () => {
    launchImageLibrary({ mediaType: 'photo', saveToPhotos:true }, onMediaSelect())
  };

  const onMediaSelect = async media => {
    if (!media.didCancel) {
      setIsUploading(true);
      const ref = storage().ref(media.assets[0].fileName);

      const task = ref.putFile(media.assets[0].uri);

      setUploadTask(task);
      task.on('state_changed', taskSnapshot => {
        setUploadTaskSnapshot(taskSnapshot);
      });

      task.then(async () => {
        const downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();
        setDownloadUrl(downloadURL);
        alert(downloadUrl)
        setIsUploading(false);
        setUploadTaskSnapshot({});
      })
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive `onMediaSelect` is a function that takes a `media` parameter and you're calling it without providing it in `onTakePhoto` and `onSelectImagePress` callbacks.

Do you know what is the the signature of the `launchCamera` function?

Comment: I didn't import the media variable, but it worked when the guy in the video did it.

Comment: Error you get clearly indicates your code is trying to call a function on the `undefined` object. Could you point me to the video you mention?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdekstqaIag&list=PL6BigWlyDofvSsDaFxIUZK1jMOZDLg4qM&index=41&ab_channel=MehmetKasimSular

Comment: Please take some time to understand API of the library you're using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker

As you can see it, `launchCamera` takes function callback as second parameter.